# Problems to export java home and to find or create .bashrc in Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, mac, java, export

I need to install a program for my studies and, this program, need java to run. When I try to perform the installation say that cannot find the JDK; since the JDK  is already installed by default in mac, the problem is export the java home.

I´ve try a lot and I cant do it! I know that I have to add a line in a .bashrc file (or .profile, or .bash_profile) I´ve created all those files, at different times but nothing...

I´m a new mac user, but I use Linux too and I dont know what happened, I just need to export java home to perform my work... and is really necessary for me to add environment variables too.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `~/.profile` file:

```
JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
```

And log out and log back in to your account.